# Angular 5/6 log-in authentication

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, angular5

recently I am working with an upgrade from legacy project to new one by using Angular 5 project with asp.net core web api.
While for the logging authentication process, usually we should **NOT** send original password to database but encrypt it, currently I am not sure which way below would be the best approach?

1. Encrypted password through Angular/Typescript then send to web api
2. Encrypted password through Angular/Typescript then send to web api then encrypt it again, finally send to database for verification.
3. Send original password to web api then inside encrypt it then send to database for verification.

   Or any suggestion that's different from above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secure way is to use Identity Provider *such as Azure AD or IdentityServer*. The recommend approach is [OAuth 2 Implicit Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit) for SPAs.

If you cannot use Identity Provider, then option 3 could be used with few modifications -

- Angular app posts username and password to server over ***HTTPS***, and the server validates with hashed password stored in database.
- If the user is valid, then response ***JSON Web Token (JWT)*** back to Angular app.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Yes I could not use Identity Provider such as OAuth2 and Auth0, so for option 3: when posts username and password over HTTPS, should I just pass the password from user input or "wrap/encrypt" it? And according to OAuth2 Implicit Flow, when token is expired, it's suggested to send a hidden sign-in request, that means I need to store the previous input username/password somewhere in my Angular App, correct?

Comment: No need to encrypt password when posting to server on HTTPS. ***Never stores username and password inside Angular app***. Instead, you could store ***refresh token*** if server turns one; then use the refresh token to acquire new token.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Yes I know there it's never be good to store username and password inside Angular app, but I am just curious about the dangerous idea behind, if I saved these information for user A in Angular app, this information should be saved on Client side right? If so only user A would grab his user information and how would user B be able to grab these information from his machine, what would be the risk here? What's the difference in between saving in Angular App vs saving in html local/session storage?